# Impossible to adjust brightness (only after sleep/wakeup) of my Thinkpad / Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts, thinkpad, brightness

I usually change my laptop's brightness with:

> <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd>: Increase/Decrease display
>   brightness

and it works well.

However, ~50% of the time, after a Sleep / Resume, **the brightness is stuck at the current level** and I cannot adjust it anymore with the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+... keyboard shortcut.

Also, adjusting the brightness slider here has no effect (usually it works!):

[image]

The only solution is to reboot the computer, and then, after this, it's possible to change the brightness.

**Why does this happen? How to solve this small issue?**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the "adaptive brightness" option is disabled in your device settings (you must google where this option is found in your particular driver software) - what happens is that this annoying feature uses the ambilight sensor (or sometimes even a webcam) to measure the ambiant light level and limits the brightness level to what it thinks 'enough' for the given lighting conditions, to 'help' you reduce the power consumption. This feature is notoriously annoying.

Comment: If you go to the Services tab in Task Manager, do you see one called Lenovo PM? It's Lenovo's own idea of power management (hence the name), and sometimes, it goes crazy on power settings, for no apparent reason. Could be that a driver it needs to function is offloaded from memory when you put your PC in standby mode, could be anything really with this piece of crêpe. Try to restart the service, and see if it things look, er, brighter...

Comment: Yes I already disabled it, and I agree that this feature is really annoying: it's the first thing I do after each format+Windows install on Thinkpad laptops :) But the current issue seems different.